# CRM 2013 SP1 - how to open an outlook email activity from a custom command button from a list view page?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

CRM 2013 SP1 - how to open an outlook email activity from a custom command button from a list view page. I've a custom command button on landing page for a lead entity, I would like to open outlook email activity from there and populate one of the lookup field of a lead as regarding for this newly opened email activity (should be opened in create mode). Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
I found a solution

We can use "document.location.href = "mailto:";"

this will open a new outlook window if outlook is installed on your machine.